# Creating gradle project in eclipse

Tags: eclipse, gradle

I play with gradle support in STS. When I try to create a gradle project via eclipse gradle wizard, I get the following error:

```
Server returned HTTP response code: 502 for URL: http://downloads.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-1.0-rc-2-all.zip
```

Therefor, there are 2 questions from my side:

1. Why does gradle even try to download the distribution from remote
   server if I have it locally installed?
2. Where shoud I indicate to
       use local version of gradle distibution?

PS. My PC is under the proxy which prohibits downloading zip archives.

Answer (score 1):

My best guess is that you chose "use Gradle wrapper" in the Gradle project import wizard. The downloads generally work fine, but might not work anymore for very old Gradle versions such as 1.0-rc-2. To solve this problem, you can either upgrade to a newer Gradle version, or point the wizard to a local Gradle installation.

Comment: exactlty, this is all my question about: how to point wizard to use local gradle installation?

Comment: Turns out this can't be done in the wizard but only under Preferences->Gradle.

Comment: I was there. There is only an opportunity to specify gradle's wrapper. I suppoose it's not what I need.

Comment: Sounds like you might be using a very old version of the plugin.

Comment: Perhaps you are using an old Eclipse version, for which no recent plugin version exists.

Comment: Spring Tool Suite 3.2

Comment: Latest is 3.6. Please accept the answer to close this Q. Example of config is at http://www.nodeclipse.org/projects/gradle/